# Collision between a sprite and a rect in PyGame

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame, collider

I'm trying to make a simple platformer game, which has code to move the camera towards a player as they jump around.

Now I have two classes: one for the player, and one for the platform.
In the `Platforms` class, I create a rect of the same size (I changed the size for simplicity to make sure everything is working) and the same position.
In the `Player` class, I want to check if the player is colliding with the platform rect.

The player *does* seem to detect the platform, but at completely different coords.

My whole code:

```
import math
import sys

import pygame

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, group, player_image_path):
        super().__init__(group)
        self.apply_gravity = True
        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_image_path).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.speed = 5

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.direction.y = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.direction.y = 1
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

    def gravity(self):
        self.rect.y += math.pi

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        if self.apply_gravity:
            self.gravity()
        self.rect.center += self.direction * self.speed

    def collision(self, col_object):
        if self.rect.colliderect(col_object.collider_rect):
            print("Ehhhhhhhhh")
            self.apply_gravity = False
        else:
            self.apply_gravity = True


class Platforms(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, group, image_path):
        super().__init__(group)
        self.rect_color = None
        self.collider_rect = None
        self.surface = display.get_surface()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        self.colorkey = self.image.get_at((0, 0))
        self.image.set_colorkey(self.colorkey)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (128 * 3, 32 * 3)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

    def draw_collider(self, x, y):
        self.rect_color = (255, 200, 255)
        self.collider_rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.rect_color,
                                              pygame.Rect(x, y, 128 * 4, 32 * 4))


class CameraGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self, surface, background_image_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.surface = surface

        self.platforms = []

        self.background_image = pygame.image.load(background_image_path).convert_alpha()
        self.background_rect = self.background_image.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0)).topleft

        self.half_x = pygame.display.get_window_size()[0] // 2
        self.half_y = pygame.display.get_window_size()[1] // 2

        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2()

    def center_camera(self, target):
        self.offset.x = target.rect.centerx - self.half_x
        self.offset.y = target.rect.centery - self.half_y
        self.offset.y -= 10

    def draw_sprites(self, player_object):
        self.center_camera(player_object)
        ground_offset_pos = self.background_rect - self.offset - pygame.math.Vector2(500, 305)
        self.surface.blit(self.background_image, ground_offset_pos)

        for sprite in sorted(self.sprites(), key=lambda sprites: sprites.rect.centery):
            offset_pos = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            if isinstance(sprite, Platforms):
                sprite.draw_collider(offset_pos.x, offset_pos.y)
                self.platforms.append(sprite)
            elif isinstance(sprite, Player):
                for platform_obj in self.platforms:
                    sprite.collision(platform_obj)
            self.surface.blit(sprite.image, offset_pos)


screen = display.set_mode((1200, 800))
screen.fill(WHITE)
display.update()

running = True

camera_group = CameraGroup(screen, 'sym_attractors.jpg')

platform = Platforms((100, 100), camera_group, 'flower_plt.jpeg')
player = Player((0, 0), camera_group, 'player.jpeg')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            sys.exit(0)

    player.input()
    player.update()

    camera_group.update()
    camera_group.draw_sprites(player)

    display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # Adjust the frame rate as needed (e.g., 60 FPS)
```

I'm also open to learn mask overlapping if relevant.

Comment: "but at completely different coords" What coordinates are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Considering you are drawing using an `offset_pos`, is there a chance you don't take that variable into account when calculating your collisions?